# ASP.Net mvc , redisplaying table/grid data on error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I am quite new to mvc and while i was building a searchform i stumbled upon a state related problem. So, in asp.net mvc there is no such thing as viewstate like in asp.net forms. The question is how to redisplay grid data if input error occurs in a view, mvc is smart enough to show entered data but search result as table is lost .I want to see the old result as well. How would you guys resolve that. Store last search result in session and if there is error in model , restore from session ? That feels a bit hacky solution.